# GNU Radio general_work() function

Tags: c++, gnuradio

I have trouble with using `general_work` function for a block which takes a vector as an input and outputs a message.

The block is a kind of demodulator. In fact it is working great if I send some data after and after (periodically).

But I need to create only one data (frame) which has a predefined size and sent it to this block. And I want this block to handle all of the items in its buffer without waiting for more data.

As I understand, it is about the buffering and scheduler structure of GNU Radio, but, I couldn't figure it out how to provide an ability to this block  to handle all the symbols of the frame that I've sent without waiting for another frame.

For example, lets say my frame has 150 symbols. The scheduler calls my `general_work` function two, three, or four times (I don't know how it decides the number of calls for my `general_work`).

However, it stops lets say at symbol #141, or 143. Every time I run it, it stops at different symbol number. If I send another frame, it completes to handle remaining items (symbols) in its buffer.

Does anybody know how can I tell the scheduler to  not wait for another frame to complete the remaining items in its buffer from the previously sent data.

---

First of all, thank you for your advices. In fact, I am studying on a link layer protocol and its implementation using SDR for my graduate thesis. Because I'm not a DSP expert, I need a wifi phy layer (transceiver). So, I decided to use an OOT module, "802.11 a/g/p Transceiver" project developed by Bastian Bloessl which is available on https://github.com/bastibl/gr-ieee802-11.git. He provided an example flow-graph (wifi_loopback.crc) to simulate the transceiver. By the way, besides the transceiver (DSP stuff) itself, he also developed some part of the data link layer issues for 802.11 such as framing and error control. In the example flow-graph, the "Message Strobe" block is used as a kind of application layer for producing data periodically and send them to a block called "OFDM MAC" which has 4 message ports (app_in, app_out, phy_in, and phy_out). In this block, the raw data which is coming from the "Message Strobe" is encapsulated by adding a header and FCS information. Then, the encapsulated data is sent (phy_out) to a hierarchical block called "Wifi PHY Hier" in order to do some DSP issues such as scrambling, coding, interleaving, symbol mapping and modulation etc. In some way, the data is converted to signal and received by the same block ("Wifi PHY Hier") and the opposite process is handled such as descrambling, decoding etc. And it gives the decoded frame to "OFDM MAC" block (phy_in). If you run this flow-graph, everything is normal. I mean, the data sent by "Message Strobe" is received correctly.

However, because I am trying to implement a kind of link layer protocol, I need some feedback from destination to source such as an ACK message. So, I decided to start by implementing a simple stop&wait protocol that the source sends a message and wait for an ACK from the destination, DATA -> ACK -> DATA -> ACK... and so on. In order to do that, I create a simple source block which sends only one data and wait for an ACK message to send another data. The data I produce with my source block is the same as the data produced by "Message Strobe". When I replace the "Message Strobe" block with my source block, I realized that something is wrong because I couldn't receive my data. So, I've followed my data in order to find which step cause this situation. There is no problem with the transmission process. In the receive process, I found the problematic block which is in the "Wifi PHY Hier" block and is the last block before this hierarchical block gives its data to "OFDM MAC" block. This problematic block which is called "OFDM Decode MAC" has two ports. The output port is a message port and the input port is complex vector. So, I reviewed the code of this block, specially, the general_work() function of it. For my particular test data, in order to complete its job correctly, it should consume 177 items to produce an output to "OFDM MAC". However, it stops consuming items after 172 items are consumed. I override the forecast() method and set ninput_items_required[0] = 177. But in this case, nothing is happened, because, as I understand, the scheduler has never see 177 items in the input buffer. As you said, this is because the block ("OFDM Decode Signal") that writes into this block's input buffer produce 172 items.

I did not go deep further yet but the interesting point is when I send a second data (in the runtime) after a period, without waiting for an ACK, the remaining 5 items of the first data I've sent are consumed in some way and received correctly by the "OFDM MAC" block. And now the second data is in the same problematic situation that the previus data has experienced.. If I send third data, the second one is also received correctly. I'm really confused. How can this be ?

Answer (score 2):

I'll comment quickly on your text, and then advise below:

> I have trouble with using `general_work` function for a block which
>   takes a vector as an input and outputs a message.

That block is, from a sample stream perspective, a *sink*. You will find that when using `sink` as a block type in `gr_modtool`, you will get a `sync_block`, which means you will only have to implement a `work`, not a `general_work`, and a `forecast`.

> The block is a kind of demodulator. In fact it is working great if I
>   send some data after and after (periodically).

So that's great!

> But I need to create only one data (frame) which has a predefined size
>   and sent it to this block. And I want this block to handle all of the
>   items in its buffer without waiting for more data.

That sounds like your block doesn't actually take *streams* of samples, but blocks. That is either a job for

- message passing (so your block would have *no* input stream, just a message port) or
- tagged stream blocks.

Sounds like the second to me.

> As I understand, it is about the buffering and scheduler structure of
>   GNU Radio, but, I couldn't figure it out how to provide an ability to
>   this block  to handle all the symbols of the frame that I've sent
>   without waiting for another frame.

*Frame* is what you make of this – to GNU Radio, your samples are just items that get written to and read from a buffer.

> For example, lets say my frame has 150 symbols. The scheduler calls my
>   `general_work` function two, three, or four times (I don't know how it
>   decides the number of calls for my `general_work`).

It doesn't decide -- that's probably the chunks in which the symbols get written into the input buffer of your block. You don't *have* to consume all of these (or any of these) if your block isn't able to produce output with the input given. Just let GNU Radio know how many items were consumed (in the sync block case, it's implicitly done with the return value; in the `general_work` case, you might have to manually call `consume` – another reason to change your block type!).

> However, it stops lets say at symbol #141, or 143. Every time I run
>   it, it stops at different symbol number. If I send another frame, it
>   completes to handle remaining items (symbols) in its buffer.

That sounds like a bug in your algorithm, not in GNU Radio. Maybe your input buffer is simply full, or maybe the block that writes into it simply doesn't provide more data?

> Does anybody know how can I tell the scheduler to  not wait for
>   another frame to complete the remaining items in its buffer from the
>   previously sent data.

The scheduler doesn't wait; as soon as there is data to be processed, it instantly "wakes" your block, and asks it to process the items.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I've edited the question and give some details about the problem I've encountered. I'd appreciate it if you can help me on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @TolgahanTÜRKER: For the first version of your question, I personally went ahead and added paragraphs to more clearly structure the text, so I could *understand* it myself. Would you mind doing that for your edit?

Answer (score 2):

I've reached Bastian, the guy who developed this OOT module. He said that the reason of the problem was a kind of padding issue. If a block called "Packet Padding2", which can be found in another OOT module that also developed by him, is used after "Wifi PHY Hier" and set the Pad Tail parameter of this block to appropriate value, the problem is solved.